# Using laravel debugbar on lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen, phpdebugbar

I'm using Lumen 5.7 and Laravel Debugbar 3.2

I made the necessary changes to these files, as specified in the manual:

**bootstrap/app.php:**

```
$app->configure('debugbar');
if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
    $app->register(Barryvdh\Debugbar\LumenServiceProvider::class);
}
```

But the debugbar doesn't appear, what do I miss?
How do I display the debugbars and use it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case was apache server that hasn't enabled mod_rewrite module. 
You can check if you have this kind of html code at the bottom of your html pages: _debugbar/assets/stylesheets.

It means that debugbar is actually working but it isn't able to load its css and js files.

To enable apache mod_rewrite module try this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite